# Adding a context menu manually

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm wondering if there's a way to force add a context menu since the "Create ISO Image" context menu is not showing up as described here: https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/tutorials/create/

Comment: Did you download & install **WinCDEmu**? It's the software that registers that menu entry.

Comment: @KeithMiller yeah I installed this: https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to show the context menu after install is to kill the `explorer.exe` process then re-spawn it again (via run task)

Answer (score 0):

The [portable](https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/portable/) version of WinCDEmu doesn't add a context menu. You need to download and install the [installer](https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/download) instead.

Comment: Hi, yes, I installed the app with https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/download/

Comment: Try uninstalling it and reinstalling as Admin.